# How to get the most frequency tuple in relational algebra?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

```
id | language
---------
01 | Java
---------
01 | Python
---------
01 | C#
---------
02 | Java
```

For example, 01 has most frequency because he learn most number of language, so how do i get the id who have most frequency??

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi. This is an obvous & easily found faq. Please read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also there are many relational algebras, so give a reference to yours including what operators you are allowed to use right now. Why did you tag this with SQL? We can guess what you mean because you gave an example but your words are not clear. Use enough words & sentences to say what you mean, not just words & fragments from that. See hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show what you researched & tried.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].  (And relational algebra is a programming language.)

Answer (score 0):

You can join with a CTE:

```
with x as (
select id, count(*) as c from my_table group by id
),
m as (select max(c) as t from x)
select x.id
  from x
  join m on x.c = m.t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 id, count(id) frequency 
from #mytable
group by id
order by frequency desc
```

Comment: can i use relational algebra writing group by??

Comment: grouping operations cannot be done using basic relational algebra operations. 
You need to build count and groupBy by yourself.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Which is a faq anyway.